# slice a csr matrix by a list of indexes - python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I 'm struggling to understand behaviour of slicing sparse matrix

I have this csr matrix say M

```
  (0, 4136)  1
  (0, 5553)  1
  (0, 9089)  1
  (0, 24104) 3
  (0, 28061) 2
```

Now I extracted index (column) and i want to slice it.
From that matrix I want a matrix

```
  (0, 4136)  1
  (0, 5553)  1
  (0, 9089)  1
  (0, 24104) 3
```

and

```
   (0, 28061) 2
```

Now if i do

```
M[0, training_set_index]
```

where `training_set_index=[4136,5553,9089, 24104]`, I get

```
  (0, 3)    3
  (0, 2)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (0, 0)    1
```

I just want to have a copy of the original matrix ( preserving indexes) with only the indexes specified in training_set_index list. Is it possible? what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This is normal indexing behavior, in `numpy` and `scipy.sparse`.  You get a new array with the desired values, but new sequential indices.

Answer (score 0):

When I hear sparsity matrix - the first thing that comes to my mind is a lot of zeros:)

One of approach is convert sparse matrix to numpy array -> do some fancy slicing -> turn back to the sparse matrix :

```
# create sparse matrix
training_set_index = [5553,24104] # for example I need this index
row = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
col = np.array([4136, 5553, 9089, 24104, 28061])
data = np.array([1, 1, 1, 3, 2])
dim_0 = (1,28062)
S = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=dim_0)

print(S)
#(0, 4136)  1
#(0, 5553)  1
#(0, 9089)  1
#(0, 24104) 3
#(0, 28061) 2

# convert to numpy array
M = S.toarray()

# create np.zeros arrays and fill them with based on training_set_index
x = np.zeros((28061, ),dtype=int)
y = np.zeros((28061, ),dtype=int)
np.add.at(x, training_set_index, M[0,training_set_index])
np.add.at(y, training_set_index, M[0,28061])

# new sparse matrix 
S_training = csr_matrix(x)

print(S_training)
#(0, 5553)  1
#(0, 24104) 3
```

Have a nice slicing!